# React Context code not working despite passing proper context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

As per the first example at [https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html] the following code should work, but it is not working. Any help? Am I misunderstanding something?

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Level1_Child1 from "./Level1_Child1";
import Level1_Child2 from "./Level1_Child2";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                String1: "AppContext Passed String1",
                String2: "AppContext Passed String2",
            }}>
            <Level1_Child1 />
            <Level1_Child2 />
        </AppContext.Provider>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export const AppContext = React.createContext({
    String1: "AppContext Default String1",
    String2: "AppContext Default String2",
});
```

Level1_Child2.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Level2_Child1 from "./Level2_Child1";

export default function Level1_Child2(Props) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h4>H4 element - Level1_Child2 - React.Fragment</h4>
            <Level2_Child1 />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Level2_Child1.js:

```
import React from "react";
import AppContext from "./App";

export default class Level2_Child1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let aquiredContext = this.context;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p>
                    Props passed using context : {aquiredContext.String1}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    {aquiredContext.String2}
                </p>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

Level2_Child1.contextType = AppContext;
```

The output is as follows :

[image: Output : no context displayed, not even the default values]

Level1_Child1 not pasted here as it does not concern us here.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for almost 2 days, I tried the following which successfully resolved my above mentioned issue. Created a seperate .js file for the context object and imported it in the necessary files, which automatically resolved the issue without doing ANY further changes to the code.

AppContext.js:

```
import React from "react";

let AppContext = React.createContext({
    String1: "AppContext Default String1",
    String2: "AppContext Default String2",
});
export default AppContext;
```

Before this, it was showing the following error in the Firefox console:

[image: react error]

Redefining it in the AppContext.js separately, resolved the issue. Don't know why, the same code was giving above error when defined in App.js.